# VS 2013 - dont delete a content file when cleaning project

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have 2 large mp4 files in my project, which must be set to 'content,copy if newer'.

Is there a way not to delete those files when Build/Clean solution?

Comment: Not sure, but an alternative might be to not include them in the actual build process, but instead add a custom step on deployment which copies the file out to be deployed - that way you're not messing with the files every time you F5, but rather only when you stage or deploy the app somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I'd add a post-build script to copy of not exists. This does not help when cleaning, but why do you have to clean anyway?

Comment: Thorsten, thanks for your reply, but I *do not* want to delete those files and have VS to copy each again (700MB), when cleaning a solution. Why I need to clean - well, I have some XML content files that are stored in such manner, that I have to clean/rebuild solution often. Thats related to project deployment/content update etc